# Get Email Address from SMTP server by User name and password?

Tags: c#

As titled, is it possible to get Email Address from SMTP server by User name and password?

The reason I want to do this is because I know some smtp server supports open relay and some don't, for that reason, I see no meaning to provide the Sender and From email address.

But in the SmtpClient class it requires a Sender and From Email email address.

Instead I want to do it by getting the actual Email Address which is the User name associated to in the SMTP server.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Essentially no. Some SMTP servers might have a proprietary API to get this information but that's per-server and wouldn't be involved in the actual SMTP dialog. For instance, if you're in an LDAP environment you could query the LDAP server and ask for the primary email address associated with a user account. That's about it.

Comment: It's not part of smtp, but if you have username and password why don't you get email address the same way?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The other reason I don't want the email address provide by the user is because the user can put other email address instead of the email address actually associated with the User name.  This email address is being used in a automatic system, which the user have to reply to the Email address whose actually sent the email and to receive it.  If in any case the user provide other Email address and the SMTP server is Open Relay enabled, it can results email being actually sent to EmailAddressA but sent as EmailAddressB and being replied to EmailAddressB.

Comment: Authentication was added a decade or two after SMTP came out but it was never intended to "look up" information or "fill in the blanks". Instead, it was intended to verify that the sender had permission to send the information using the pre-existing syntax which required a `MAIL FROM` command. Sometimes the account that authenticates doesn't even have an "email address" in the first place, it could just be a system process. It appears that you don't have control over the SMTP system so you are dealing with untrusted users as well as untrusted system admins. This might not end well.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Now I understand, in another word, the identity for authenticate can have totally no association with an email address.  The SMTP server can send email using any email address as From/Sender, the authentication process using UserName and Password is for to check does this User has permission to send Email.  And here is my assumption, in the case of Email Relay disabled SMTP server, the UserName will also used to check if this UserName has permission to set a different From/Sender for the Email being send.  Am I right?

Comment: @ChrisHaas And in the case of Email Replay disabled SMTP server, if UserName has no permission to set the From/Sender, it can results the Email not being sent or use a default EmailAddress to send the email address?

Comment: There's no real rules for authentication and "open relay" isn't a definitive thing, either. I can create a server with a username and password of "abc" that allows anyone to send to anyone. Its not "open", true, they've authenticated, but you can still relay all you want. However, generally speaking I would assume that anyone that's implemented authentication has assumed the responsibility of making sure that they are behaving correctly.